# adb sideload CM,it shows error

Tags: android, sony, cyanogenmod

Ubuntu-14.04.
Sony z1.

I download cm-12.1-20151226-NIGHTLY-honami.zip.follow device wiki.

I meet this problem in **Click here to continue instructions using Cyanogen Recovery**step 3, i don't konw what is "update.zip".is it "cm-12.1-20151226-NIGHTLY-honami.zip"?

I used `sudo adb sideload cm-12.1-20151226-NIGHTLY-honami.zip`,it said `error: protocol fault (no status)`.

I don't konw how to solve this problem.i don't konw how to install CM in my Sony z1.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Android.SE](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you're absolutely stuck like I was, try a different host device or new installation instead of giving up! → https://android.stackexchange.com/a/234460/340401
@cactus you should vote for migration then

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing TWRP recovery for Xperia Z1 and then use the installer within TWRP to install the cyanogenmod zip.

https://twrp.me/devices/sonyxperiaz1.html